Python - Selenium - Not able to find element in Web Page (https://instamembers.appspot.com/)
The intent of the current code is to find the "Register" text and click on it as a button. It looks/acts like a button.
It might be something about these components.
Here is the Inspection - right-clicking on the 'Register' button
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

url = "https://instamembers.appspot.com/"

print("SET WEB DRIVER")
service = Service(executable_path="chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

print("GO TO URL:", url)
driver.get(url)
print("GOT WEB url")

time.sleep(2)

try:
    print("FIND 'Register'")
    # Try to find the Register button using various methods
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Register')]"))
    )
    print("FOUND 'Register'")
    print("ASSIGN 'Register' BUTTON???")
    register_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Register')]")
    register_button.click()
    print("Clicked Register button")

except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")

finally:
    driver.quit()

----------------------- SCREEN PRINTOUT ---------------------
SET WEB DRIVER
GO TO URL: https://instamembers.appspot.com/
GOT WEB url
FIND 'Register'
FOUND 'Register'
ASSIGN 'Register' BUTTON???
An error occurred: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=129.0.6668.90)
Stacktrace: .....

Tried multiple versions of find_element..

Your code was able to find the element, but it was an element type that is not clickable.  I'm betting that the element with "Register" text isn't the actual button -- it's some other element, like a <div> or a <span>.

You can see from the 'register_button' details that the method used to find the button is not working, although using 
By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Register')]
with any of the other buttons (replacing 'Register' with the appropriate name) does work.
Change the search to be more specific seems to do the trick
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

url = "https://instamembers.appspot.com/"

print("SET WEB DRIVER")
service = Service(executable_path=r"F:\PycharmProjects\Chromedriver_129.0.6668.91\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

print("GO TO URL:", url)
driver.get(url)
print("GOT WEB url")

time.sleep(2)

try:
    print("FIND 'Register'")
    # Try to find the Register button using various methods
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Register')]"))
    )
    print("FOUND 'Register'")
    print("ASSIGN 'Register' BUTTON???")

    ### Actual X Path
    # //*[@id="zd"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/p

    register_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Register')]")
    ### This returns an empty string
    print(f"Button Text: {register_button.text}")

    ### Provide a bit more detail
    register_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id=\"zd\"] //*[contains(text(), 'Register')]")
    ### This returns 'Register'
    print(f"Button Text: {register_button.text}")

    register_button.click()

    print("Clicked Register button")

    ### Stop execution for a bit to show button was clicked
    time.sleep(30)

except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")

finally:
    driver.quit()


